# enabling notifications

Tags: iphone, xcode4, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I would like to enable notifications in my iphone app. So, I modify in app ID:

[image]

After that, I generate again Development and Distribution Provisioning Profiles and installed in my xcode.

My app is a tabbed based application, the first tab is UITableViewController

I add this lines:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{    
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];

   return YES;
}
```

So, I suppose I should have my app in the list of app installed with notifications in my iphone, but it isnt.

Did I miss some step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep. According to [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIApplication) and [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1) you should add the `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes` method in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, which should the look something like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{    
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];

    return YES;
}
```

Depending on which Types you registered your app will appear in the notifications section and you can turn on and off the different types (sound, badge, banner).

Hope that helps.

Comment: I change the lines I had before for this and still doesnt work. Can I add this liens in a UITableViewController?

Comment: No. This method definetely belongs into your AppDelegate.m. The method is - as the name says - called, when the app did finish launching, but only when in the AppDelegate, so put it there and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

First enable your remote notification in app delegate. See below :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    // Let the device know we want to receive push notifications
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
        (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I thy this, without the self.window lines because of the other solution, but still doesnt work. Is it possible to add this to a UITableController? where should I add this?

Comment: u have get any alert msg like this http://cdn2.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/Basic-App-2-Allow-Notifications-333x500.jpg

Comment: if no, check your bundleId is matching with ur provisioning profile.

Comment: No, I dont get this alert, but I check the bundleID<->provisioning profile, its ok

Comment: no, u don't want to alert this one. which automatically ask When the app starts and registers for push notifications, it shows a message to inform the user that this app wishes to send push notifications.

Comment: yes, I undertood what you were saying after write the comment, so, I deleted my coment because I realized I was wrong